# JQuery UI Dialog With Dynamically Loading URLs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, user-interface, dialog

i have generated anchors like

```
<a href="approvaledit.php?MSRID=<?php echo $MSRID; ?>" class="exampleLink"  >Approval</a>
```

and i want to open the approvaledit.php with jquery ui dialogue and i have succeed however, because they all have same class name all the generated links open the first href, how can this be fixed?

```
<a href="approvaledit.php?MSRID=<?php echo $MSRID; ?>" class="exampleLink"  >Approval</a>




var $modalDialog = $('<div/>', { 
          'class': 'exampleModal', 
          'id': 'exampleModal1' 
        })

        .appendTo('body')
        .dialog({
           dialogClass: 'my-extra-class',
           resizable: true,
           title:'PR Approval',
           autoOpen: false,
           width:'auto',
           height:'auto',
           show: 'fold',
           position:  { my: "right top", at: "top" },
            modal: true,
              close: function(event, ui) {
          location.reload();
     }
        }).css("font-size", "11px"); 


        $(function () {
            $('a.exampleLink').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $('a.exampleLink:first').attr('href');
                $modalDialog.load(url, function(){
                 $('h4').hide();   $( "#btnCancel" ).hide(); 
                });

                $modalDialog.dialog("open");
            });
        });
```

Comment: `var url = $(this).attr('href');` ???

Comment: yess lol thnx mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var url = $(this).attr('href');